# Output file after Docker image is created through Dockerfile

Tags: mono, docker

I'm creating a Dockerfile to build my Docker image.  I was wondering what the best way, or if it's even possible, to create a log file of some sort that can show the results of the build and see if there were any errors in the process.  For example, right now I have this:

```
monoVersion="3.8.0"
mkdir ~/mono
curl http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-$monoVersion.tar.bz2 | tar xj --strip-components 1 -C ~/mono
cd ~/mono
git apply /src/mono-fix-20131106.patch
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make -j 2
make install
```

in a install.sh script.  In my Dockerfile I have:

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER crystaltwix
ADD . /src
RUN  cd /src ; ./install.sh
```

I'd like a way that I can look at the output after the image is created so every time I grab a different version of Mono, or do something similar when creating a new image, I can look after the image is created to see if any errors were generated.  Is this possible?  Or is that "connection" to the image being built closed once the Dockerfile is completed.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I have been seeing for years (well before docker though docker makes it easier) is to have the script save it's output to a build log with the resulting image so that when you use the image and find a bug you can **be sure you know hot *this* image was created**.

```
RUN  cd /src ; ./install.sh | tee buildlog
```